# Shift value to some point in binary number

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, avr

I wonder if it is possible to do the following.
For instance, I have a number 00001110. I am shifting it left. -> 00011100....
But the question is if it possible to start setting value in carry flag not from the seventh bit but from the sixth. There is a command - ROL it shifts a seventh bit into C flag, and than stores this value in the zero bit.
But I need to do like this ,but don't do anything with seventh bit, and store sixth bit in C flag and than also store it in zero bit. I mean when the value is 01110000 the next value should be 01100001.
Is it possible to do like this. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Just to use "if statement" to check condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Instruction  Carry  Reg value
-----------  -----  ---------
PUSH           x    01110000
ROL            0    1110000x
ROL            1    110000x0    b6 now in carry
POP            1    01110000
ROL            0    11100001    b6 now to b0
AND $7Fh       x    01100001
```

The answer above does not preserve b7 it clears it. This preserves b7.

```
MOV     r1,r0       ;copy r0
ROL     r0
ROL     r0          ;b6 in Carry
MOV     r0,r1       ;restore r0
ROL     r0          ;shift in original b6 to b0
ROL     r0          ;replace b7 in r0 with b7 in r1
ROL     r1
ROR     r0
```